# Реализация своего vector C++, удаление последнего элемента через pop_back()

Tags: c++, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

namespace s21 {
    template <class T>
    class vector {
        public:
            using value_type = T;
            using reference = T&;
            using const_reference = const T&;
            using iterator = T*;
            using const_iterator = const T*;
            using size_type = std::size_t;
        
        public:
            vector();
            ~vector();
            void push_back(const_reference value);
            const_reference back();
            void pop_back();

        private:
            T *array_;
            size_t size_;
            size_t capacity_;
    };
}

namespace s21 {
    template <class T> 
    vector<T>::vector() : array_(new T[1]), size_(0), capacity_(1) {}

    template <class T> 
    vector<T>::~vector() {
        std::cout << array_[5];
        delete [] array_;
    }

    template <class T>
    void vector<T>::push_back(const_reference value) {
        if (size_ == capacity_) {
            capacity_ += 10;
            T *tmp = new T[capacity_];
            std::copy(array_, array_ + size_, tmp);
            delete [] array_;
            array_ = tmp;
        } 
        array_[size_] = value;
        size_++;
    }

    template <class T>
    typename vector<T>::const_reference vector<T>::back() {
        if (size_ == 0) {
            throw(std::out_of_range("vector is empty"));
        }
        return array_[size_ - 1];
    }

    template <class T>
    void vector<T>::pop_back() {
        if (size_ == 0) {
            throw(std::out_of_range("Vector is empty"));
        }
        size_--;
        array_[size_].~T(); // тут пытаюсь деструктор на последний элемент вызвать, но похоже оно не работает
                            // так как все равно потом к этому элементу можно обратиться
    }
}


int main() {
    s21::vector <int> steck_;
    steck_.push_back(1);
    steck_.push_back(2);
    steck_.push_back(3);
    steck_.push_back(4);
    steck_.push_back(5);
    steck_.push_back(5);
    steck_.push_back(5);
    steck_.pop_back();
    steck_.pop_back();
    steck_.pop_back();
    steck_.pop_back();
    std::cout << steck_.back() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Погуглил, кто-то пишет, что достаточно просто уменьшить size, а с самим элементом ничего не делать, другие пишут, что оригинальный vector таки удаляет этот элемент. Нашёл вот такой способ `array_[size_].~T()`, но судя по всему, он не работает? Я все ещё могу обратиться к как бы удалённым элементам (в деструкторе ~vector() для проверки вывожу элемент, который должен был удалиться).

Answer (score 0):

При удалении вашего вектора как такового в его деструкторе у вас вызывается

```
delete [] array_;
```

Т.е. будет вызван деструктор для каждого элемента массива. Так имеет ли смысл вызывать деструктор при `pop_back()`, в особенности рискуя тем, что такой деструктор *будет вызван дважды* (второй раз при удалении вектора) и для чего-то посложнее `int` может привести к массе неприятностей? Конечно, можно вызывать деструктор и в `pop_back()`, но тогда надо принять специальные меры во избежание упомянутых неприятностей.
Как именно этого добиться — отдельный вопрос, в обычном векторе из стандартной библиотеки этим занимается аллокатор.

Теперь об обращении к удаленным... Как вы себе представляете невозможность обращения? Что это вообще значит — удаленный элемент? Особенно простой, типа `int`, который деструктор не запортит (а вообще ничего не сделает)? Как физическое вырезание куска памяти из платы? :) Память-то на месте, так почему к ней нельзя обратиться? Можно вообще обратиться к памяти по "левому" адресу, просто это будет неопределенное поведение.

Т.е. окончательный ответ на вторую часть вашего вопроса остается открытым, пока мы не утрясем терминологическую путаницу и ваши ожидания. Итак, что такое в вашем представлении "удаленный элемент массива"? В массиве `int a[] = { 1,2,3,4}` как вы себе представляете удаление элемента 4?

Comment: Да я и сам не знаю, что я под этим ввиду имею) Чтобы там оставалось то же, что и у оригинального вектора при pop_back.

Comment: Тогда надо читать стандарт, что именно требуется, а что зависит от реализации... Вообще-то при добавлении/удалении этим всем занимается аллокатор, который может быть и переписан, но, боюсь, такая реализация (с аллокатором) выходит за рамки вашей задачи... Да, стандартно при удалении элемента сразу вызывается его деструктор, но при этом предпринимаются особые меры для того, чтобы такой деструктор не был вызван дважды. Простого `a[i].~T()` явно недостаточно...

Comment: `a[i].~T()` недостаточно в том смысле, что потом повторно вызовется деструктор на уже удаленную память? Или недостаточно для удаления этого элемента? Просто у меня `a[i].~T()` вообще не работает и не удаляет ничего, к элементу всё ещё можно обратиться после этого

Comment: Недостаточно в смысле повторного вызова. Но вы "опять 25" — что вы хотите от удаления? Чтобы при попытке обратиться с удаленному элементу происходило что? Взрыв компьютера? Удар током программиста? ***ЧТО ВЫ ХОТИТЕ ПОЛУЧИТЬ?***

Comment: Ну думал должно вылезать seg fault какое-нибудь, если там ничего нет)

Comment: Ну так допишите себе такое поведение, что мешает-то? Но по большому счету это можно трактовать как выход за границы массива, а это UB, так что гарантировать конкретные неприятности можете только вы сами, но не компилятор.

Comment: Сейчас заполнил оригинальный вектор 1, 2, 3, 4 элементами, сделал pop_back, в итоге `cout<<vector[3]` возвращает 4...)

Comment: Да, но попробуйте вернуть `.at(3)`...